# How to apply a localization to a javascript string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, localization

I assigned a string to a javascript string object, such like :

```
var word = "Please input correct verb"
```

I want this string be in control by resource file in asp.net project. Does it provide the function to replace the string using a ASP.NET syntax to switch languages?

```
<%$ Resources:Registration, correctverb%>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are various l18n projects for JavaScript, e.g. http://i18next.com/

If you have ResX files in your ASP project and you want them as JavaScript or JSON files you can [convert them here](http://localise.biz/free/converter/xml-to-js); or via the [REST API](http://localise.biz/free/converter/api) you could convert a resource file as follows:

```
$ curl --data-binary @messages.resx \
   http://localise.biz/api/convert/resx/messages.json
```

(example in cURL, which I guess you may not have if you're on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

A common approach for this is creating an [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that evaluates requests for say files with the extension *.js.axd (or whatever extension you come up with) and then parse the javascript file by replacing defined tokens with the actual localized resource value.

It may be costly only the first time the file is requested but then everything should run smoothly if caching is applied. Here's an [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) of how to create a handler, parsing the file should be trivial. You could use the same syntax to define localized strings on your file: <% LocalizedResourceName %>